# Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets and that $f: A \rightarrow B$ is onto. Does being onto guarantee the sets are finite?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets and that $f: A \rightarrow B$ is onto.  Determine which of the following statements are true:
>
> - If $A$ is finite then $B$ is finite.
> - If $B$ is finite, then $A$ is finite.

My defintion for onto is: a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be onto provided for each $ y \in Y$ there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x)= y$.  I also have the statement "Thus a function is onto if the range is equal to the codomain."

I am thinking that if $B$ is finite then $A$ is finite is the true statement and if $A$ is finite then $B$ is finite is the false statement. I think this statement is false.

Is this correct? How do I begin a proof or give a counterexample?

Comment: "There is no guarantee that an onto function sends one $x$ value to one and only one $y$ value" - actually, the "function" part of "onto function" guarantees this.  Why don't you write down some examples of $A$s and $B$s and refine your conjecture?

Comment: In fact, the first statement is true, whereas the second is false.

Comment: You need to stop thinking about this problem for a little while and go learn what a function is.

Comment: @WillO thank you for that great comment.  I realized what I wrote didn't make sense after posting. Thanks.

Comment: @AlyssaWallace:  Thank you for taking the comment seriously.  Best of luck with all your studies.

Comment: The answers have suggested some counterexamples for statement 2, but here's an especially simple one: Take $A$ to be any infinite set you want, and take $B$ to be your favorite one-element set.  There is exactly one function $f:A\to B$, and it is onto.

Answer (score 0):

An onto function need not be one-to-one. Figure out which side doesn't need to be the "one".

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A = \Bbb N$, and consider $B = \{0,1,2,\dots,b-1\}$, for some fixed positive integer $b$.

You should know that for any natural number $a$, we can write:

$a = qb + r$, where $r \in B$, and that the natural numbers $q,r$ (also known as "quotient and remainder") are uniquely determined by $a$ and $b$.

Thus we can define $f:A \to B$ by:

$f(a) = r$, and this function is onto. But $B$ is finite, and $A$ is infinite.

Comment: Or simpler yet, you could define $f(x)=\min(x,b-1)$.

Comment: Indeed, there are *many* projections of an infinite set onto a finite one.

Answer (score 0):

Statement 2 is not always necessarily true.

Consider a function floor()%finitenumber which maps real numbers to integer set. Then A can be infinite but B is always finite.

Comment: The first statement _is_ necessarily always true, though.

Comment: @Ilham: Sorry, I mistyped. In any case, it looked as if you are claiming that _each_ of the statements is sometimes-untrue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assume first that $A = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ is finite. Since $f$ is onto, we have $f(A) = B$. From this it is easy to see that $B$ must be finite.

On the other hand, if $B = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_m \}$ is finite, you could for example construct a function $f: \mathbb N \to B$, by setting $f(n) = x_n$ for $n = 1, \ldots, m$, and $f(n) = x_1$ for $n \in \mathbb N \backslash \{1, \ldots, m\}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "from this it is easy to see that B must be infinite?"

Comment: Yeah, I mean we obviously have $f(A) = \{ f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n) \} = B$, which means that $\vert B \vert \leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:A \rightarrow B$ is an onto map then $|B|\leq |A|.$ So if $A$ is a finite set then $B$ is also a finite set.

Comment: Can you please explain how you make the inequality statement?

Comment: Actually the proof is by Axiom of Choice that if there as an onto map from A to B then there is one one map from B to A.

Comment: And if there is one one map from B to A then B is equivalent to a subset of A so cardinality of B is less than or equal to that of A.